# Documentation generator for python3

Tags: documentation, python-3.x, documentation-generation

I recently felt the urge to generate documentation for my little project. I thought it would be fairly easy since I had a set of nice docstrings. Turns out the whole process is much more complicated in python 3.1.

Here's what I tried:

- epydoc: Fails because it's for python 2. 2to3 didn't solve the problems
- pydoc: I can't find any information how can you generate documentation for your own modules, seems like a server for reading python docs offline
- sphinx: Most promising so far, I have built it from their repository however it fails with a very cryptic error message (*jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: b'b"\'sphinx.jinja2glue.idgen object\' has no attribute \'next\'"*)

My question is: what should I do now? Are there any other non-commercial documentation generators that work with python3?

Comment: I think Sphinx is the way to go, to solve the issue you can post a question on http://groups.google.com/group/sphinx-dev, the authors of the software read it.

Comment: Okay, I posted and we'll see how it goes ;-)

Comment: For simple projects where Sphinx feels like an overkill, you could try [pdoc](https://pdoc3.github.io/pdoc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently in Jinja, something is doing X.next(). In Python 3 that's next(x) instead. It should be a simple fix.

Comment: Thanks! Although that wasn't the case at all, your comment inspired me to dive into sphinx code. After trying to understand how jinja2 works, I found that in _build/lib/sphinx/jinja2glue.py_ the idgen object indeed had no next() method... it was named __next__(). After fixing it all works well!

Comment: @Wiesław Herr: Yes, because under Python 3, the nethod should be called `x.__next__`, and you should call it with next(x). So do NOT rename the method, change the call, as I said above.

Comment: Ah, now I understand how it works and why 2to3 changed it. So you where right from the start ;-) Thanks!